# Get focus(or scroll into view) to a panel using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, panel, js-scrollintoview

I am setting up a form in which user will be able to see their selection of radio button(of a particular value) on a button click.

i am able to get the radio button focus and make the page to scroll to it, but  want the parent `panel-body` to get focused on page just like `scrollintoview()` but that's not working.

also used `.parents(".panel-body")` before `.focus()` not working either..
``

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="input-opt">
        <p>Select options..</p>
        <div rel="tool-tip">
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="lead">
                    <input id="rad1" tabindex="1" required="required" value="one" type="radio">
                    one
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="lead">
                    <input id="rad2" tabindex="1" required="required" value="two" type="radio">
                    two
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio">
                <label class="lead">
                    <input id="rad3" tabindex="1" required="required" value="three" type="radio">
                    three
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var ncyc = $("input[value='two']:checked").length;
    $("input[value*='two']:checked:eq(" + target + ")").focus().keyup();

    target = target + 1;
    if (target == ncyc) {
        target = 0;
    }
});
```

Code above enables only the radio button get into focus...when not using .parents(".panel-body")......i want the whole div to be in the visible frame

Comment: Please provide complete working example of your html and js code

Comment: updated @dganenco

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is `target` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If parent is `<div>` it needs `tabindex` attribute. Try like this

```
$("input[value*='three']:checked:eq(" + target + ")")
.parent(".panel-body").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

or add tabindex attribute to html tag like

```
<div class="panel-body" tabindex="-1">
</div>
```

and use in your code like old expression:

```
$("input[value*='three']:checked:eq(" + target + ")").parents(".panel-body").focus();
```

**UPDATED:**
*If you don't want to change html you can do same thing through jquery code like the following

```
$("input[value*='three']:checked:eq(" + target + ")").parents(".panel-body").attr('tabindex','-1').focus();
```

Comment: hi... thats a user script i am working on...... the thing is i dont want to change the html.....any possible way without changing the file

Comment: Definitely, instead of changing the HTML, you can change through jquery like the following code:
`$("input[value*='three']:checked:eq(" + target + ")").parents(".panel-body").attr('tabindex','-1').focus();`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your html file you can scroll to your div using such approach:

```
//your stuff goes here
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.panel-body').offset().top }, 'fast');
```